# Remove borders from windows of specific class

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to write a layout modifier very similar that would allow me to remove borders based on class name property of the windows. The code is largely based on  [XMonad.Layout.NoBorders](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.13/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html) with the exception of the logic executing in the X monad to allow filtering based on [className](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.13/docs/XMonad-ManageHook.html#v:className). The code I've got so far is:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}

module  XMonad.Layout.ExcludeBorders  where

import           Control.Monad
import           Data.Monoid
import           XMonad
import           XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier
import           XMonad.StackSet hiding (filter)

setBorders :: [Window] -> Dimension -> X ()
setBorders ws bw =
  withDisplay $ \d -> mapM_ (\w -> io $ setWindowBorderWidth d w bw) ws

data ExcludeBorders p a =
  ExcludeBorders p
                 [a]
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

excludeBorders :: p -> l a -> ModifiedLayout (ExcludeBorders p) l a
excludeBorders qs = ModifiedLayout (ExcludeBorders qs [])

instance (Show p, Read (ExcludeBorders p Window), Excludes p) =>
         LayoutModifier (ExcludeBorders p) Window where
  unhook (ExcludeBorders _p s) = asks (borderWidth . config) >>= setBorders s
  redoLayout (ExcludeBorders p _s) _ mst wrs = do
    ws <- withWindowSet (\wset -> excludes p wset mst wrs)
    setBorders ws 0
    return (wrs, Just $ ExcludeBorders p ws)

class Excludes p where
  excludes ::
       p
    -> WindowSet
    -> Maybe (Stack Window)
    -> [(Window, Rectangle)]
    -> X [Window]

data ExcludeProp =
  ExcludeClassName String
  deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

instance Excludes [ExcludeProp] where
  excludes qs _wset mst _wrs =
    flip filterM (integrate' mst) $ \w ->
      fmap (getAny . mconcat) .
      sequenceA . map (fmap Any . flip runQuery w . toQuery) $
      qs

toQuery :: ExcludeProp -> Query Bool
toQuery (ExcludeClassName s) = className =? s
```

which can be used in the layout hook as follows:

```hs
excludeBorders [ExcludeClassName "Krunner", ExcludeClassName "plasmashell"]
```

Unfortunately as is it doesn't have the desired effect, or any effect at all.. Being completely new to writing layout modifiers I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and perhaps I misunderstand how the `redoLayout` function is supposed to work. Any pointers would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**: Some further testing shows this may be a peculiarity of KDE / plasma windows and / or issue with my config rather that anything to do with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the main logic was fine except for not accounting for floating windows. Changing the `Excludes` instance as follows:

```hs
instance Excludes [ExcludeProp] where
  excludes qs wset mst _wrs =
    let ws = integrate' mst ++ [w | (w, _) <- Map.toList . floating $ wset]
    in flip filterM ws $ \w ->
         fmap (getAny . mconcat) .
         sequenceA . map (fmap Any . flip runQuery w . toQuery) $
         qs
```

makes it work for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this feature has been recently added to the XMonad.Layout.NoBorders module:

[`hasBorder :: Bool -> ManageHook`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.15/docs/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html#v:hasBorder).

ManageHook for sending HasBorder messages:

```hs
   className =? "foo" --> hasBorder True
```